# ROS Voice recognition

Tags: c++, voice-recognition, ros, pocketsphinx, festival

Short summary of what I tried to do and what it's actually doing.

In my project I have two simple nodes: one for listening and publishing, and another for speaking and subscribing. I named them listeningNode and speakingNode, respectively.

The task I wanted to achieve was pretty simple, I would have the user say "remember me" which would be recognized as a keyword and be published to `voiceCommandCallback` method in the speaking node so my robot could say "Okay, please say your name". Then, back at the listening node, on top of publishing that keyphrase it will also call the method `recognize_from_mic_with_dict()` which as you can guess will run using a dictionary of names.

This `recognize_from_mic_with_dict()` method will be listening for a name and will attempt to publish that name to `namesCallback()` in the listening node and this is where I check if what got published was an actual name or if it was just gibberish, in which case I would kindly ask the user to repeat his/her name and subscribe once again to `recognize_from_mic_with_dict()` so it could listen once more.

This sounds more complicated that it probably has to be but it's the only way I could think of achieving this "mode switching". The problem is that if it hears gibberish it will say "I'm sorry, I did not quite hear that. Please repeat that!" and I would like to know if there is a way to make the listening node ignore anything that the robot says because it's attempting to recognize names from its own sentence.

Answer (score 0):

you can cast it as a feedback control problem.
given that :

- u is the user speech signal
- r is the output signal of the robot speaker,
- h the feedback path function,
- s=h*r the feedback signal; * refers to convolution
- y = s + u = h*r + u the input signal of the microphone

the problem is to estimate ĥ and therefore ŝ (r is already known),
so an estimation of the user speech signal is given by û =  y - ŝ = y - ĥ * r

Comment: Um, having a bit of a hard time understanding your answer.. cast what exactly, as a "fedback control problem" ?

Comment: feedback refers to acoustic coupling of the loudspeaker to the microphone.
to make the listening node ignore what the robot says jut filter it out, this is what feedback control do.

Comment: check this link :
ftp://ftp.esat.kuleuven.be/sista/spriet/reports/06-153.pdf